# Usage of suspendCancellableCoroutine in fetching user location in KMM project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to create a class that would implement fetching user's location in KMM project. I found a code that uses suspendCancellableCoroutine, but I don't really know if I am using it correctly.

**LocationProvider(Android):**

```kotlin
actual class LocationProvider(private val context: Context){


    private val fusedLocationClient by lazy {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    actual suspend fun getCurrentLocation(): Location? = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        val priority = Priority.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(priority, CancellationTokenSource().token).addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            location?.let {
                continuation.safeResume(Location(it.latitude, it.longitude)) { continuation.cancel() }
            } ?: run {
                continuation.resumeWithException(Exception("Unable to get current location"))
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            continuation.resumeWithException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I am concerned about here is using continuation.cancel(). It is a callback from **safeResume()** method that checks if continuation is active, and if its not, then the callback is invoked. So the way I think of this is that if this **suspendCancellableCoroutine** is no longer active, it has to be cancelled somehow. But is it good approach?

```kotlin
inline fun <T> Continuation<T>.safeResume(value: T, onExceptionCalled: () -> Unit) {
    if (this is CancellableContinuation) {
        if (isActive)
            resume(value)
        else
            onExceptionCalled()
    } else throw Exception("Must use suspendCancellableCoroutine instead of suspendCoroutine")
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when you cancel an inactive continuation. However resuming a cancelled continuation is a state violation that throws an exception, hence the check. Also it's weird that this safeResume is not an extension on `CancellableContinuation` and instead does a runtime check that causes an exception.